# If I donate 100 USD to a charity using PayPal Giving Fund, does the charity receive 100 USD?

Tags: credit-card, fees, paypal, charity

I have a question about [PayPal Giving Fund](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/givingfund/home).

About a year ago, I called them on the phone (I don't remember what number I called, but it was a line intended for donors). I asked the representative this question: If I donated $100 to a charity on PayPal Giving Fund using a credit card, how much money would the charity ultimately receive? They told me that the charity would receive $100. **Is this accurate? Is it misleading?**

**Context and caveats**

- This is not an attack on PayPal or the phone representative. It just
  seems to me like there could be some complexity involved that would
  make it hard to guarantee this. For example, maybe in PayPal's mind
  "$100 going to the charity" just means "PayPal doesn't take a cut,"
  but some other credit card interchange fee is still paid by the
  charity. I don't know how these things work.
- While I was on the phone with that representative, I briefly re-asked
  the question a few different ways to try to get at the complexity
  there. They were very patient with me, seemed to know what they were
  talking about, and kept saying "yes."
- That's consistent with [what PayPal says](https://www.paypal.com/merchantapps/appcenter/streamlineoperations/givingfund?locale.x=en_US#:%7E:text=PayPal%20Giving%20Fund%20doesn%27t,charged%20a%20fee%20for%20services.) and with what [this
  competitor site says](https://givebutter.com/blog/paypal-giving). However, I know there have been issues in
  the past with PayPal not being appropriately transparent about this
  program and creating issues for charities (same third-party link).
- Also, whenever I ask about this I am told that this is stupid, I
  should just write a check or else use the most prominent donation option
  available on a charity's website, that everything else in an
  administrative pain for the charity and there must be a catch
  somewhere. For those reasons, I'm still not convinced by my phone
  call.
- In case you're wondering why I don't just write a check or use the most prominent displayed option on a charity's website, the answer is that I would like to get credit card rewards for my donations if possible. My target charity is GiveDirectly, which is pretty cozy with PayPal. So I presume some of the downsides (administrative burden, delays, shadiness) would not apply to me. **Interesting PSA:** per [Harper-Reinstate Monica](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/44366/harper-reinstate-monica), given my circumstances I might get more out of my charitable contributions by transferring stocks to a DAF and then immediately donating those stocks to a charity. The avoided capital gains tax could be more than the credit card rewards. (In this case the savings come from Uncle Sam rather than the bank; determine the ethics of that as you will. To be fair, I also don't know what transaction costs are associated with the donation of assets from the DAF to the charity.) Thanks to @keshlam as well.

Comment: Biased source (they're a PPGF competitor), but interesting: https://givebutter.com/blog/paypal-giving

Comment: You’re asking a convoluted bunch of questions which all boil down to “what percentage of my donation goes to the charity?”

Answer (score 4):

501c3 manager here.

### Don't worry about it. Really.

Every charity manager knows that fundraising is a difficult task and a serious expense. You can spend 20-40% of the money you earn just in the expenses of the campaign.   It's maddening. I can't tell you how many times I wore out my hands stuffing envelopes for results that were disappointing.

In fact, most of the charity spam phone calls and postal mail you get is done by *for-profit fundraisers* who do the fundraising on a cost-plus basis. You may have noticed they'll spend 10 times the value of your gift trying to solicit more gifts, that is for-profit fundraisers scatter-shotting the entire donor list to find whales.  There have been cases in California where the fundraiser actually ended up collecting 91% of the money that went to the charity.

So, having to pay maybe 3% credit card transaction fees on a freely given donation that did not need to be fundraised, is really not objectionable to any nonprofit manager worth their salt.

If you want a donation receipt, *ask for one*.  They are required above certain donation limits, but even below that they should do it if you ask.  Of course, that still costs a stamp.

I could see PayPal waiving the credit card fees for charities.  However, as far as the tax deductibility of a particular charity, I would not count on a credit card bill line item unless the named entity on the bill **only gives to tax-deductible charities**.  Only certain charities are tax deductible. The IRS has a database of those.

A great many entities which ask for "donations" which are not tax deductible - people on Youtube, Patreon, Kickstarter, political entities, churches who are politically active, many things technically called nonprofits - it is a morass.

Comment: Interesting! If I ask for a donation receipt, does that usually come with information on how much of my donation ended up going to the charity, and/or what transaction costs they incurred?

In this particular case, I think PayPal Giving Fund is itself a charity that then gives to other charities. Not sure whether that addresses your point about entities that only give to tax-deductible charities (in this particular case).

Comment: @BeeePollen that is quite likely. "A charity which gives to other charities" is called a Donor Advised Fund. I have a somewhat different type of DAF at Fidelity Charitable, but they have a high upfront commitment to start the fund and you can store money in the fund. Giving through them is very advantageous because they screen charities, and conceal my name when needed.

Comment: For me the attraction of setting up my own DAF account was that it gives me a way to donate appreciated securities (and avoid the capital gains tax on them) even if the target charity isn't set up to accept same. And it lets me aggregate most of my donations into a single transaction rather than needing 50 lines on my tax return to include everything. Plus being able to automate those donations on a monthly or yearly basis. Downside is that some money does to go supporting the DAF's maintenance, but it isn't much compared to what I'm pumping through the fund.

Comment: @Keshlam yeah, Fidelity Charitable charges only 0.6% per year for the money I store in the DAF, and nothing otherwise (Well the mutual funds have a trivial expense ratio e.g. 0.12%).  I asked them bluntly how they feel about "Free Riders" who don't store money in their DAFs and *merely* use them as a free pipeline to convert complex donations they immediately re-donate. They said they don't mind at all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica interesting! I didn't realize you could do that. If I understand correctly, you're saying that I can hold stocks(/whatever) *outside* of a DAF, they can appreciate *outside* of the DAF, and then I can donate them to the DAF and then to the charity without paying capital gains?

Comment: Yep, just as you could donate them directly to the charity and not pay cg. Essentially, the DAF _is_ a charity that funds other charities.

Comment: @BeeePollen *Someone* must pay the capital gains tax.  If it's the DAF/charity, guess what their tax rate is? 0% :)

Comment: So I came into this thinking that I should try to use PayPal Giving Fund to get an extra 5% on my donations. But it sounds like I might do better, in many cases by donating through a DAF and save on capital gains instead. Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica and @keshlam!

Comment: You may be able to donate appreciated shares directly to your charity. Larger ones can advise you on their preferred procedure. Smaller ones may not understand the question.

Comment: @BeeePollen Absolutely. Transfer the stocks *as stocks* out of the IRA and into a same-bank brokerage account. Then, talk to your DAF about how to process them.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I could do the same thing with stocks that are not held in an IRA, correct?

Comment: @BeeePollen Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Paypal is writing off the fee they aren't charging as a deductable donation of services, and treating the rest as an advertising expense. They want to get you in the habit of using their system.

But this is easily tested: Make a donation, then see if the receipt from the charity matches what you paid. If it matches, and you don't see a fee on your receipt from PayPal, there is no fee.

Comment: I don't think that this means anything. The receipt would match the donation, but the charity may still be charged fees for using the payment processor. This is no different than using a credit card in a store - the receipt is what you paid, but the merchant may receive less.

Comment: Maybe. I'd still say asking the charity is the simplest answer if you don't trust PayPal's honesty.

Comment: That's a good idea, I will try that.